# How to display only columns with specific text in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

Is there a simple way to display only columns which contain the text `achievement` in the first row in Google Sheets? I know it is possible to to in JavaScript, but I was wondering if there was a way to do this via filters or a non-scripting method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this with the [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197) function. Say this is your data, in the range `A1:C` of `Sheet1`:

```
      A           B              C
1  Firstname    Lastname    Achievement
2  John         Doe         Hot dog eating champ
3  Lisa         Simpson     Saxophone virtuoso
4  John         Snow        Knows Nothing
5  Assim        Hussein     Personal best
     ...
```

This function, on `Sheet2`, say, will display only columns with `achievement` in the first row. Neat thing... the comparison is case-insensitive, and will match multiple columns with the same header text.

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!A1:C,ARRAYFORMULA(if(Sheet1!A1:C1="achievement",true,false)))
```

or simply:

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!A1:C,ARRAYFORMULA(Sheet1!A1:C1="achievement"))
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: How would I reference another sheet with this? `=FILTER(indirect(Main!A1:Main!D:D),ARRAYFORMULA(if(indirect(Main!A1):indirect(Main!D1)="achievement",true,false)))` didnt seem to work (with a sheet named Main)

Comment: Updated to show reference to range in another sheet. Since a range can't span sheets, you only need to include the sheet reference at the front of a contiguous range, as in `Main!A1:D`. The `INDIRECT` function is for something else altogether.

Comment: If I could give you multiple I would :)